to replace XML node with Text found in the same XML file

HEllo friends,
I havent been programming for a while and found myself not struggling with this small project at my table. I have a XMl export of Invoices from one system and need to import into another one. Problem is that the source Program doesnt include COdes of products only empty node. so I am writting a simple WInForms C# utulity which will take the name (<inv:text>**PPL doručení do Parcelshopu**</inv:text>) of the product search in predefined dictionary to get the correct product Code and replace node <inv:code /> with <inv:code>S_PPL_M3</inv:code>.
One XMl has many <inv:invoice>
One Invoice has one <inv:invoiceDetail>
One </inv:invoiceDetail> has multiple <inv:invoiceItem>
One <inv:invoiceItem> has One <inv:text> and one <inv:code>
I am trying to use LINQ to XMl object. But then I struggle with logic:

Get one  invoiceItem node
Get child <inv:text> and its text into variable
Get the right Item code from dictionary (I know how to do this)
Within same InvoiceItem replace</inv:code> with <inv:code>Correct COde</inv:code>
And mainly to have this repeating thrughout the XMl  to the end.

Would be great to get some ideas how I can do this from you expert guys. Thanks a lot
XDocument? doc = XDocument.Load(path);

Please post your XML as snippet intead of image.

I'd strongly advise against that. Fix the source, don't tamper with the data. In an unfortunate context, this may be considered fraudulent (worst case).
